# Differentiate dark and light areas in image

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

My problem is that I want to differentiate the light and dark areas in the following image to generate a binary mask.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZRKB.jpg

An approximation to the output can be this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UuJb.jpg

I've tried a lot of things but the results still have some noise or I lost a lot of data, like in this image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUyjY.png

I've used python with opencv and numpy, gaussian filters, opening, closing, etc...
Somebody have some idea to doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I first reduced the size of the image using pyrDown then used CLAHE to equalize the histogram. I used medianblur as this will create patches then used opening 3 times. After that it was a simple binary_inv threshold. If you want to get the original image size, use cv2.pyrUp on image. By playing with the parameters you can manage to get better results.

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("7ZRKB.jpg",0)
image = cv2.pyrDown(image)
clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2.0, tileGridSize=(16,16))
image = clahe.apply(image)

image = cv2.medianBlur(image, 7)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT,(5,5))
image = cv2.morphologyEx(image, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=3)

ret,image = cv2.threshold(image, 150, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
cv2.imshow("image",image)

cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Nice!! Really cool result, thanks! I've one question about your code: Why did you define the kernel in that way and not with a numpy array? Your way creates a different result or improve the calculations speed?

Comment: It is easier to modify the structuring element if you want to. By using cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE it will create a matrix with an ellipse as mask in it. There is also an cv2.MORPH_CROSS but it doesn't apply here.
Also I didn't need to import numpy (which is used by cv2 anyway)